# Unable to restore volume after unmute

Tags: javascript, html

In my HTML5 video player, if the current volume is `0.5` and if I mute and unmute back, the volume restores to `0.5` which is correct. However, if the volume is other than `0.5`, it is still restoring to `0.5` after muting and unmuting.

I tried to create a backup of volume before muting and restored the backup on unmuting. Still it does not work.

Here is my code:

```
$("#mute_button").click(function(){
    if(video.muted == false){
        var volume_backup = video.volume;    // create backup
        video.muted = true;
        $("#mute_button").prop("value", "Unmute");
        $("#volume").val(0);
    }
    else{
        video.muted = false;
        $("#mute_button").prop("value", "Mute");
        video.volume = volume_backup;    // restore backup
        $("#volume").val(volume_backup);
    }
});
```

Why is my logic not working?

Comment: declare your backup variable as global, then try it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

careless mistake only...

```
var volume_backup;
$("#mute_button").click(function(){
            if(video.muted == false){
                volume_backup = video.volume;
                video.muted = true;
                $("#mute_button").prop("value", "Unmute");
                $("#volume").val(0);
            }
            else{
                video.muted = false;
                $("#mute_button").prop("value", "Mute");
                video.volume = volume_backup;
                $("#volume").val(volume_backup);
            }
        });
```